# SLF4J.properties make it work in android

Tags: android, slf4j

I am using SLF4J in various java projects, and works great. However I am trying it on android, and I can not make it see the properties file.

According to their instructions, (https://github.com/interdroid/slf4android) I have placed my SLF4J.properties in src/org/slf4j 
and have set:
default.log.level=warn

I am checking \bin\classes\org\slf4j, and my file is there.
However I still get my debug log messages. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.
Was using version slf4j-android-1.6.1-RC1.jar
and apparently it is working as described in version 1.6.2 which I compiled from github.

Comment: You should accept your own answer as an indication for future visitors of this page that that is actually the solution.